# Firebase Auth without domain authorization?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am able to explore and test the features of Firebase on various servers, whether it be localhost or online. However, In order to do this I need to whitelist domains under "Authorised domains" for signing in. The issue with this is that I am trying to create a javascript widget that can be added to multiple websites and be able to use firebase on any domain.

Is it possible disable the domain authorization or perhaps a way to add a wildcard for any domains? I am just not sure how to get around this challenge. How would I allow signing in on any domain if my javascript widget is loaded?

Comment: That is not the recommended behavior. You would basically be turning off security. All developers are expected to whitelist authorized domains. Otherwise, anyone can trick your users to sign in to their app and they would be able to access all their data in your app.

Comment: Thanks @bojeil. So what would the best practice be to allow signin on any website? I would like my javascript file to be loaded on any website to allow uses to access to the features. Alternatively, if there is perhaps a way to dynamically add whitelisted domains? Then for each website there is just a process for them to register their domains. Otherwise, would I need to create a custom login process?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the use case? What features would these websites be able to access from your service?

Comment: Sure. The idea is to create a javascript framework which would access a firebase database based on an authenticated user. This javascript framework would ideally be able to be added to any website. Then when a user lands on a website containing this script, I would like them to be able to login to access their own data. Not sure if I am making sense...

Comment: @AdrianHolmes Were you able to figure out this? I'm in the same boat! :)

Comment: I dropped the project for a while. I think the solution has something to do with tokens though. I think you can pass tokens around which is not dependent on domain...